# fetch doesn't set headers in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I try to get a POST request working via the `fetch()` function. The problem is that my headers won't be set and the request fails.

Here is an example code of my request:

```
fetch('https://google.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
          'X-FOO-BAR': 'bla'
        },
        mode: "no-cors",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          data: "here"
        })
      });
```

My main problem is, that the `Content-Type` will be set to `text/plain`, which is why my request fails. I added the `X-FOO-BAR` header just to see if it gets set. But it won't get set.

Comment: Where does the fetch come from? From here: https://davidwalsh.name/fetch ?

Comment: yeah. the native fetch function in modern browsers.

Comment: maybe read https://davidwalsh.name/fetch? he uses an request object

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606244/using-fetch-api-with-mode-no-cors-can-t-set-request-headers