# Using fetch API with mode: 'no-cors', can’t set request headers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I am trying to hit a service end point and the service is a login service
I am using the authentication type as basic ,The code is in react and using the fetch library however even if i set the headers field in my request I am unable to see the values of corresponding headers in my request in network tab?

Following is the code  :

```
var obj = {
  method: 'GET' ,
  mode : 'no-cors',
  headers: {
      'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Authorization',
      'Authorization': 'Basic amFzcGVyYWRtaW46amFzcGVyYWRtaW4=',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Origin': ''
  },
  credentials: 'include'
};
fetch('http://myreport:8082/jasperserver/rest/login/', obj ).then(…
```

---

**Popup where its asking me for username and password**
[image: Popup where its asking me for username and password]

---

**Request and response calls from the network tabs**
[image: Request and response calls from the network tabs]

Comment: this seems to be a cross origin request why have you set mode to 'no-cors'?

Comment: try to remove mode: no-cors and use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors or something similar for your backend platform

Answer (score 29):

None of your headers are `CORS-safelisted`, so they can not be attached to the request.

Explanation:

1. `no-cors` request mode sets `guard` property for a headers object to `request-no-cors`
2. To append a [name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-name)/[value](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-value) (name/value) pair to a Headers object (headers), browser have to run these steps:

   1. [Normalize](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-value-normalize) value.
   2. If name is not a [name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-name) or value is not a [value](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-value), then throw a TypeError.
   3. If guard is "immutable", then throw a TypeError.
   4. Otherwise, if guard is "request" and name is a forbidden header name, return.
   5. Otherwise, if guard is `"request-no-cors"` and name/value is not a `CORS-safelisted request-header`, return. **← your scenario**
   6. Otherwise, if guard is "response" and name is a forbidden response-header name, return.
   7. Append name/value to header list.
3. `CORS-safelisted request-header` (case-insensitive):

   - `Accept`
   - `Accept-Language`
   - `Content-Language`
   - `Content-Type`, but only if the value is one of:

     - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
     - `multipart/form-data`
     - `text/plain`

You can learn more about fetch's `Headers class` specs here:
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#headers-class

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors'` basically normalizes the request to be a "simple" one, for example, the server will receive `Content-Type: text/plain` instead of `application/json` that you have in your code snippet. I find this behavior quite strange/interesting but that's the way it is. mode:no-cors also avoids triggering preflight.