# Error when fetching data with Headers (no return)

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to use a API (https://tracker.gg/developers/docs/titles/csgo) and it's not working properly.
When I try to make a request it asks for headers inside fetch (never used headers, only regular fetch and a url).
Doing a little search I came up with:

```
async function fetchData() {

    const response = await fetch('https://public-api.tracker.gg/v2/csgo/standard/profile/steam/76561198008049283', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'TRN-Api-Key': 'XXXX-XXXXX-XXX-XXXXXX-XXX', //here goes the key that I got for this app.
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
    },
    mode: 'no-cors',
   })
   const second = await response.json();
   console.log(second);
}
```

And when I call this function I get two errors inside console:

1. GET https://public-api.tracker.gg/v2/csgo/standard/profile/steam/76561198008049283 net::ERR_ABORTED 401
2. Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

My knowledge is too basic at the moment and I'd like to get some insights of what I'm missing and what I could do to learn a little more about fetching data and how to do a validations when needed (like a authentication key)

Comment: 401 error doesn't mean you have error with your code. The 401 error code represented the request sent by the client to the server that lacks valid authentication credentials. I guess it is the problem about the api key.

Comment: One more thing that could very possibly be the problem is that you need to include credentials in your request.... For example your fetch request after the method parameter you could (and possibly should) have `credentials: 'include',` that way the server sees that you are including credentials (as some servers require this to be set).

Comment: Like others have mentioned, the `401` probably refers to the corresponding [HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) which would indicate that either your API key is invalid or the API isn't receiving your key. Have you tried to recreate your request with e.g. cURL or Wget? That's where I would start.

Comment: The developers of the API strictly state that you should have the API key kept secret (Private) meaning it isn't a public Key it is a private key (intended for server to server use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after tinkering with the request I realized something that should have been obvious...
 The request you are trying to make should **NOT** occur in the browser unless you are on tracker.gg's site. Simply put you should be making this request from your app (**server**). Server to server will have no effect on cors.
Now lets get into the dirty details of why? Firstly your request will not include the 'TRN-Api-Key' header because it is not CORS-safelisted (as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606244/using-fetch-api-with-mode-no-cors-can-t-set-request-headers) brilliant answer tells us). Basically when you make the fetch request it removes the headers that are not safelisted and thus 'TRN-Api-Key' is removed from your header request and does not go to the API. Hence why you are seeing that "no api key being sent" because it isn't being sent. If you remove the mode: 'no-cors' then the key will be sent but fails CORS. If you don't have cors being used then the request must be made on tracker.gg to have the correct cors site. 
Thus the developers of this project thought (and for good reason) that you would only be making this request on a server (It simply isn't a secure way to handle the api key having it on the front-end). If you instead make an api to work with their api your app can use your own custom server without knowing the api key (using some form of authentication of course).
Simply put it is **Your game server**'s responsibility to take care of this API key and use it responsibiliy for the users of your app. Please read up on the docs of the api you are trying to access (also please read that answer as it is interesting).
Final answer: The API key should be used for server to server communcation as it was intended (not in the browser).