# Using fetch() with a bearer token and mode: 'no-cors' produces a 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from an API by doing this:

```
  const url = `https://......`

  console.log('DEBUG TOKEN', `Bearer ${token}`) // is correct
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postString),
  })
```

The problem is, that it returns a 401 (unauthorized) error.
If I do the same request using curl, it works:

```bash
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ........asdfasdf....." \
  -d '{"my":"json","data":"here"}' \
  "https://......"
```

I am using the same payload, token, and address for both `fetch()` and curl.

What is wrong with my fetch() code here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using fetch API with mode: 'no-cors', can’t set request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606244/using-fetch-api-with-mode-no-cors-can-t-set-request-headers)

Comment: You specified you don't want to use CORS, i.e. you want a "simple request" only. Simple requests can't have extra headers for example, so those get omitted. You need to use CORS.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
    mode: 'no-cors',
```

As far as I understand, it removes authorization headers too. Without it, it works.